# Other vhost aliases next to Foreman

Tags: foreman, puppet-foreman

After installing foreman on default URL, other aliases like `/phpmyadmin` or `/ganglia` don´t work anymore; `"Page not found"`.

What´s the best way to get them working again next to the foreman GUI and installation, especially if the foreman master server should not be managed by puppet?

Currently I bound services like `phpmyadmin` and `ganglia-webfrontend` to another port and it`s working, but I don't think it's very suitable.

Thanks a lot!

Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You should move Foreman to a different Vhost, like `foreman.example.com`.

Please note that the puppet masters' certificate has an alternative name `foreman.example.com` on it, similar to `puppet` or `puppet.example.com`. So you will need to re-create the foreman hosts' cert with alt names.

```
puppet cert list --all | grep puppet.example.com
```

You should be able to use a different cert as well (not tested!)

```
puppet cert generate foreman.example.com
```

Config for the classes looks like this for me:

```
class { '::foreman':
  foreman_url => 'https://foreman.example.com',
  servername  => 'foreman.example.com,
  # if you use another cert
  client_ssl_cert => '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/foreman.example.com.pem',
  client_ssl_key  => '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/foreman.example.com.pem',
  server_ssl_cert => '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/certs/foreman.example.com.pem',
  server_ssl_key  => '/var/lib/puppet/ssl/private_keys/foreman.example.com.pem',
}

class { '::puppet':
  server_foreman_url => 'https://foreman.example.com',
}

class { '::foreman_proxy':
  foreman_base_url => 'https://foreman.example.com',
}
```

You should be able to set all the values in foreman-installer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most correct answer is that your foreman server should be dedicated to foreman, and should not have other miscellaneous services running. The foreman-installer uses puppet and set the state of the machine to be the way the installer defines it. I don't believe there is a provision for maintaining other aliases. However, you could probably reconfigure them after the fact, and not run the foreman-installer again, as it will revert any "manual" changes to the configurations that it manages.

Comment: I don´t think this can be the idea behind a foreman host server?! I am constructing a compute cluster with one master server and X Working nodes. Of course foreman(=master server) manages the nodes configuration/updating, integrated in visual monitoring by ganglia on masterserver and for managing mysql by users phpmyadmin from masterserver. For each small and simple application a single server, even a virtual server can  be only be contrary to the intention of the inventor... I think!